# How to get a checked input to load a page in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form where I need the checked input to load the form action url based what is checked. I have the following js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(":checkbox").change (function(){ 
          if($(this).attr("checked")){
                   //need code that goes here
          }
        });

      });   
  }(jQuery));
</script>
```

This is the HTML/PHP used:

```
<div class="Dropdown-menu careers-Dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuBlog">
  <form class="Dropdown-menuForm" action="/careers/#CareersList-section" method="post">
    <?php 
      foreach ( $locterms as $term ): ?>
        <input id ="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" name="location[]" type="checkbox" class="Dropdown-formInput example" value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"
          <?php if (in_array($term->slug, $locationsArray)) echo 'checked'; ?>
        >
        <label for="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" class="Dropdown-formLabel"><?php echo $term->name; ?></label><br>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    <!-- <input class="Dropdown-submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: You'll need to use ajax to load the php page without reloading the page the user is on, clicking boxes.

Comment: action based on checkbox ? two actions will be performed if there are two checkboxes selected ?

Comment: @Jigar good catch. Yeah, he'll need to also give each checkbox a unique ID and trigger the event when it is changed.

Comment: Yeah I need the action from this line:       <form class="Dropdown-menuForm" action="/careers/#CareersList-section" method="post">  @Jigar

Comment: @MikeL5799 with ajax, you can send form data to the server the same as if you submitted a form in the traditional way, except ajax allows you to send the form data without reloading the page, which allows you to get results back and modify your page in real time, making an otherwise static page, dynamic.

Comment: @MikeL5799 Sorry. I am still not sure what you are trying to do. I think I did similar thing, I had one form for two actions based on selected radio button(checkbox in your case), so I changed the form action when selection was changed. Do you want the code for same ?

Comment: Basically I want whatever is checked to load the action associated with that checked item without using a submit button @Jigar

Comment: @MikeL5799 `$('.Dropdown-menuForm').attr('action', $(this).val())` something like this ?